# How do I implement a control that wraps text with multiple styles and allows touch actions on individual text components?

Tags: ios, uitableview, word-wrap

I've attached a picture taken from the Trover iOS app. It shows a table cell rendering user comments for a posted item (trove?). I am trying to implement similar functionality and it's not clear what a good implementation method would be.

The requirements are:

1) Text components with varying styles can be rendered within a rectangle and wrap to multiple lines

2) Each text component can have it's own 'selected' state and touch action (i.e. like a UIButton)

3) The overall height of the control can be calculated (for use in a UITableViewCell when calculating the height of the cell).

Example pic from Trover (public data so I have not obscured user names):

[image: trover pic]

Thanks for any help/suggestions! Would love an example implementation of anything similar if anyone can point me to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use NSAttributedStrings and Core Text for rendering. There are a few controls that make this easier such as [OHAttributedLabel](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel) and [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel).

Answer (score 0):

In order to format the text differently (as the names are bold and a different color) the easiest way to do this would be to embed a `UIWebView` in the cell, and format the text as such.  You could use hyperlinks (`<a>` tags) with some formatted link that you intercept with

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

Return `NO` obviously to prevent the webview from loading what is a very incorrect link, but you can parse that link to determine what was clicked (was it a username?  Whose username was it?), and proceed with your navigation accordingly

Comment: I thought about using a web view but it's not clear how to calc the height needed without actually creating/rendering the view.

Comment: Yeah, detecting text size is rather difficult, but you would have to do it anyway if you were to use built-in objects (`UILabel`, `UITextField`, `UITextView`) as each one does not support different formats for different sections of text.

Comment: using an individual UILabel, calc'ing text size is not that difficult. trying to do it with multiple labels and/or buttons while also laying them out in a custom way is hard. With a UIWebView, I don't know how to calc the height of the webview within the cell at all, certainly not w/o first rendering the web view. This seems to rule out a UIWebView as an effective implementation within a cell with varying lines of text. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Perhaps, but either way, you need to lay out a bunch of `UILabel`s programmatically, or use a `UIWebView`, those are the ways that I see this being possible